# Can I attach a warning handler to scalac from sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, compiler-warnings, reporters

I want CI to know wether the number of warnings in a project isn't increasing. I could parse the output of sbt, but that seems fragile. Can I pass a custom reporter to scalac that I can use to serialize out a warning list/summary so I can easily compare runs? If so, how?

Comment: Maybe through `compilerReporter`?